# Get rank of user using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a Sql Server database, I have a table in which a column with a user's score:

[image]

I want to create a query that will fetch the ranking of a user, for example if the input will be "user4" I will get 1 and if the input will be "user2" I will get 5 etc.

I have written such a query in MySql but now I need to implement it in SQL server.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Experts claim that cynicism isn't very good for the skin ;)

Comment: And people here tend to appreciate people showing that they have put some effort into the solving the problem themselves.

Comment: That's true, but never the less I did try before asking. I will make a point of it to include code in future questions.

Comment: @Udi I: You might also want to make a point of actually including a *question* in future questions. (This post reads more like a status report on your current development efforts.)

Comment: I agree that this question is not well formed, though I think "I want to create a query that will fetch the ranking of a user, for example if the input will be "user4" I will get 1 and if the input will be "user2" I will get 5 etc." explains quite clearly what I am asking.

Comment: Guys: was it truly unclear that this person has/had a problem in need of a solution or are we just feeling particularly pedantic today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `rank()`, `row_number()`, or `dense_rank()`.  SQL Server provides these functions:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by score desc) as therank
from table t;
```

The difference between the three function is in how they handle ties.  Your sample data has no ties, so they would all return the same thing.

EDIT:

For a specific user, you can use a subquery:

```
select therank
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by score desc) as therank
      from table t
     ) t
where user = @user;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add the condition for a specific user? will I need to use subquery?

Answer (score -1):

```
select rank 
from
(
  select username, rank() over (order by score desc) as rank
  from table
) t
where username = 'user4'
```

Comment: This will return a rank of `1` for any user you put in the `WHERE` clause.